# php - Selecting data from different table , match and count the numbers that has the same value

Tags: php, mysql

**Edit:** I have 2 tables in my database: `files` and `user_logs`. I want to print all the values ​​in `files` and match them with similar values in `user_logs`.

The columns in `user_logs` and `files` are the same:

```
  +++++++++++++++++++++
  + fileName | fileId +
  +++++++++++++++++++++
```

And I want the following output:

```
  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
  + fileName | no. of same values +
  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
  + fileNo1 |          3          +
  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
  + fileNo2 |          1          +
  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
  + fileNo3 |          0          +
  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

I don't understand what I researched. Here's my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT user_logs.fileName,count(*) as c FROM user_logs JOIN files ON user_logs.fileId = files.fileId UNION ALL SELECT files.fileName as file from files a group by a.fileId DESC ";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $num_row = $row['c'];
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row['fileName']."</td>";
        echo "<td><a href='#' >".$num_row ." / 2 Schools Clicked</a></td>";      
    echo "</tr>";
    }
```

Comment: Please read this: [stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i'm sorry. I am very poor in english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you, I think you want something like this as your query:

```
SELECT fileName, IF(t.cnt IS NULL, 0, t.cnt) AS c
FROM files LEFT JOIN
(SELECT count(*) AS cnt, fileId FROM user_logs GROUP BY fileId) AS t
ON files.fileId = t.fileId
ORDER BY fileName
```